# simplify onPress through currying?

Tags: javascript, react-native, refactoring, currying

I was testing out how to combine 2 very similar functions into one to reduce my code base and was wondering if ti can be done through currying. It is a new concept to me, so I have failed and now am asking for help.

```js
const yesNoEnum = {
  none: null,
  no: 0,
  yes: 1,
};  

  noButtonOnPress = () => {
    const isSelected = this.state.selected === yesNoEnum.no;

    if (isSelected) {
      this.setState({
        selected: yesNoEnum.none,
      });
      return;
    }

    this.setState({
      selected: yesNoEnum.no,
    });
  }

  yesButtonOnPress = () => {
    const isSelected = this.state.selected === yesNoEnum.yes;

    if (isSelected) {
      this.setState({
        selected: yesNoEnum.none,
      });
      return;
    }

    this.setState({
      selected: yesNoEnum.yes,
    });
  }
  
    isSelected = () => {
    const selected = {
      no: this.state.selected === yesNoEnum.no,
      yes: this.state.selected === yesNoEnum.yes,
    };
```

I was wondering if the noButton and yesButton clicks could be combined. This is what I attempted before:

```js
  handleButtonPress = (shouldCheckYes) = () => {
    const isSelected = this.state.selected === shouldCheckYes ? yesNoEnum.yes : yesNoEnum.no;

    if (isSelected) {
      this.setState({
        selected: yesNoEnum.none,
      });
      return;
    }

    this.setState({
      selected: shouldCheckYes ? yesNoEnum.yes : yesNoEnum.no,
    });
  }
```

Comment: you *say* you were *trying* - but you haven't shown what you tried. Best way to learn is from your *mistakes*, not just asking people to write code for you - simple answer is "yes, they can be combined if you really want to"

Comment: yes, just pass the difference to a wrapper, use index style prop access to hit the passed-in key, and return the function, almost as-is

Comment: @dandavis can you give a small example I can work off of?

Comment: @StuffedPoblano - please don't use comments for code you should've put in the question :p - but that's close - if instead `shouldCheckYes` is a string of value `yes` or `no` ... then you can use either of your existing blocks of code, and instead of `yesNoEnum.no` use `yesNoEnum[shouldCheckYes]` - personally I'd change the paramater name to `yesno` or something simpler

Comment: @JaromandaX okay I will try that. Thanks. I also edited my post and removed that code filled comment.

Comment: much easier to read :p is that code not working? do you change your other functions to something like `noButtonOnPress = () => handleButtonPress (false),`

Comment: my linter is telling me that `shouldCheckYes` is undefined.